# Buffering a media content, while playing the other one in Windows Media Player using C#

Tags: c#, windows-media-player, buffering

I am developing an application in C# that has a form with Windows Media Player embedded inside. There are several links to some online content in my app. and I want user to change the content from one to another with a button click. Since WMP spent some time while buffering for the next content, I want to continue playing the current content. There is an event called "Buffering" in `AXWindowsMediaPlayer` class that signals when media player finishes buffering the content. But I could not achieve this with a single AXWindowsMediaPlayer object. Whatever I did, I could not continue to play the first content while buffering the second. :(

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest two instances of the Player control that you swap out as needed.

Alternatively, if the connection is fast enough cache each item on the local system and play from there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am fairly new to .NET and C# programming. I will happy if you explain a little bit. For example, how can I cache the content into a local system. Which class or method should I use to get the stream from the WMP?